# Make a "Region Pool" based on cities distance

Tags: anylogic

I am building a simple Logistic Simulation with `AnyLogic 7.1`. I have a `group of cities` with a Pool for the Trucks. Each city has a different Pool because the number of trucks is based on the city population. I want to make a `"Group Pool"` based on distance, so I would add the Pools from the selected cities and make a `"Region Pool"` for that.

The distance that this "Group" will reach must be editable (for example in a variable)

Is that possible to be made with AnyLogic? If yes, please tell me where to start, I have a very begging level. Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about having a pool of pools?

If so, I'm not sure that anylogic supports that directly, but you could make you own list, like an arraylist with either the pools or the agent in the pools.

are there any reason why you want to use a pool object? any specific function you need?

Comment: Yes, a Pool of Pools. The reason is that a specific region will add all the Truck Pools from the cities and if the Region Pool runs out of Trucks then I need to do something else

Comment: well it is hard to figure out what your exact problem is, maybe if you give some code examples of how you imagine it to be it'll be easier to figure out. try and use a function to combine and output the needed pools